# Problem when i try type password after su command execute

Tags: command-line, server, bash, permissions, ssh

Today i was encounter strange situation when i login via ssh and enter command /bin/su. When I try to type my password with keyboard it allow me only one character and then throw me in next line. When try this in console it's work as it should.

In meantime i did remove this user and create new user but problem still persist. I did not copy paste password!OS is Centos 7.9.2009, First character of password is letter A.
Command which Command executed to connect server is ssh -i privatekey_rsa user@server

Same question I asked on stackoverflow.com and they told me to try here.
Below is replication of my problem.

```
[user@server ~]$ /bin/su
Password:
hisisatest.123
su: Permission denied
[user@server ~]$ hisisatest.123
-bash: hisisatest.123: command not found
```

Comment: [so] directed you to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - Centos is off-topic here

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times, you need to use `sudo su` instead of just `su` alone.

You're typing `/bin/su` (which is the same as `su`) but you have to type `sudo` before it. So here's exactly what you'd type: `sudo /bin/su`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Alex Thank you for your answer, this is fine workaround, but in this server i am the only one who connect to. This user is just to make connection to server and it's not sudoer, then I execute /bin/su command and switch to root. It was working last 2 years and now suddenly not.

Comment: Hi, @Frosty35, I just want to remember you, when you type `su root` (or just `su`) you must provide the root's password not the user's one. In addition while the root's account is enabled you could try to use the `login` command instead of `su`.